# Isomorphisms between Groups (Integers mod n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> 1. How many isomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$  to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{9}$?
> 2. How many isomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$  to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$?

My "solution":

1. There are $6$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, $6$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$, and $1$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Thus $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{9}$ has $6$ generators. An isomorphism will take generators to generators - there will be $6*6=36$ isomorphism.
2. Similar strategy.

The solution:

1. $6$ isomorphisms
2. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is not cyclic thus no isomorphism exists.

I think I see #2 -- $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, the orders of components are not relatively prime, so they won't combine to a cyclic group. Is that correct?

I however, fail to see #1. Thoughts?

Comment: Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism for 1. Then actually since $1$ generates $\mathbb Z_{18}$, $\phi$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(1)$. Since there are $6$ generators in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_9$, there are $6$ isomorphisms. For instance, $5$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_{18}$, so if $\phi(1) = (1,1)$, then $\phi(5)$ will be enforced to be $(5,5) = (1,5)$.

Comment: Ah - so if I'm counting Isomorphisms between two cyclic groups, I only have to count generators in the target?

Comment: Note: $\mathbb{Z_2}×\mathbb{Z_9}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{18}}$ since $2$ and $9$ relatively prime. So basically you have to find, number of automorphism of group $\mathbb{Z_{18}}$ i.e you have to find $|Aut(\mathbb{Z_{18}})|$ and under automorphism generator must maps to a generator :-)

Comment: ^That's a good way to think about it, thanks!